# Memory leak UIImage in Swift 4 ImageIO_jpeg_Data

Tags: ios, swift, instruments

I have two UIViewController in which the photos are displayed, the fact is that when I switch between them, then I add 50-70mb of RAM and so on ad infinitum.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

'

```
var tags: [TagForRecipe] = [] // CoreData entity

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tagCell", for: indexPath) as! TagsTableViewCell

    cell.tags.text = tags[indexPath.row].nameTag
    cell.images.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: (tags[indexPath.row].image as! URL).path)

    return cell
}



import UIKit

class TagsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var images: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var tags: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

'

Comment: @Adrian added TagsTableViewCell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImage in TableView eating memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597954/uiimage-in-tableview-eating-memory)

Comment: Are you paginating your table view or loading "à gogo" the number of images you have on your data source ? How many images you have in your data source btw ?

Comment: @GIJOW There may be different numbers

Comment: Yes I understand. I meant in your example. But never mind, I would follow the link above. Seems that you're loading web images on your `cellForRowAt`

Comment: contentsOfFile does not do any caching, so when you reuse each cell, it creates a new UIImage and keeps them in the memory. You should remove the previous from the memory before setting the new one.

Comment: @GIJOW This is an image from FileManager

Comment: @aytek Please tell me how to remove?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611542/memory-problems-with-uiimagecontentsoffile) out

Comment: @aytek I did not quite understand what's different there

Comment: @AlexanderGovorukhin are you loading images from Photo Library or application context?

Comment: @aytek app context

Comment: @aytek Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: @aytek How do I compress an image before adding it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any memory leak in your graph. It just shows the amount of the memory used so far. Memory leak is the second line, and if there is one it's marked with red colour. For more information check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html) link

If your images are too large, then try to resize them. This will improve the performance and your tableview will be smooth while scrolling.

Comment: But the memory is not cleaned, but hangs forever

Comment: @AlexanderGovorukhin I don't think you have a memory problem, If you had you would receive a memory warning and your app would be closed. Please follow my advice and try to reduce the size of the images. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28566113/1259775) might also help

Comment: @AlexanderGovorukhin You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314412/how-to-resize-image-in-swift) for resizing images

Answer (score 1):

You should set your image using contentOfFiles not from storyboard.
Delete your image outlet and the image in storyboard and then use this code in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let splashPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bg", ofType: "png") {
        backgroundImgView.image = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: splashPath)
    }
}
```